# Create buffer from centroid to 20 m from edges in polyon R

Tags: r, buffer, polygon, edges, centroid

I have a shapefile that consist of sea and river polygons within a state boundary (cropped and masked from landcover map (raster) and state boundaries (polygon shapefile)). Within a state boundary, I have multiple polygons (in my case over 1500 different polygons) and I would like to extract the area from the edges and 20 m inward (like an inner buffer). But for my case, all my polygons aren't perfectly shaped, some are rivers, some are just squares (10*10 m from rasterfile) and some are big lakes. My problem is how to create this "inner buffer" for polygons since all polygons, or even not all parts of polygon need to have the buffer (since they are smaller than 40 m, buffer 20m on each side)).

Let me show you my code and how far I have come.

```
poly <- jvk_18[53,]
cropped <- crop(mark_data, poly, snap = "near")
masked <- mask(cropped, poly)
sjo <- (masked == 61)
sjo <- clump(sjo, directions = 8, gaps = T)
```

> So here is just the extraction, `cropping`, `masking` and `clumping` sea and rivers within a state boundary.

Further I have transformed my data to MULTIPOLYGON

```
test <- st_as_stars(sjo)
test <- st_as_sf(test, merge = TRUE)
test <- st_cast(test, "MULTIPOLYGON")
```

After this, I found the `st_centroid` function to detect the middle point for the polygon. Here my next question is if it is possible to create the `buffer` from the centroid to 20 m from the edges? Is this possible, and in that case, how?

```
pol <- test[904, ]
cent <- st_centroid(pol)
```

Lastly, as mentioned at the beginning, I would like to remove this "inner part", to in the end only get the 20 m from edges and inward.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working from the center out, couldn't you work from the edges in, by as you said using an inner buffer?

It would be easier to help you with a reproducible example, but given an sf object `poly` containing your polygons, I would do something like:

```
core <- st_buffer(poly, -20) %>% st_union()    # this will shrink your edges by your desired amount, 20m (and union to tidy up)

diff <- st_difference(poly, core)  # difference will leave you with the 20 m ring, removing the core
```

Of course that will make small polygons disappear... you could probably set a conditional buffer size, but please post an example if you want help with it!

Comment: Wow, BIG THANKS! It actually worked. I was a bit worried that it wouldn't work with polygons that were smaller than the buffer itself, but the computer only provides me with a warning and still gives me the area of the polygon, "with buffer included".

Comment: Great! Could you please consider voting up or accepting the answer? I'm new here too :)